# Can a combining character be used alone in Unicode?

Tags: unicode

Let's take [COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm), for example. Its [browser test page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/browsertest.htm) does include it alone in the page, but it reacts in a strange way: I can't select it with my mouse, and if I try to interact with it in the DOM inspector, it feels like it's not part of the text at all (there's no *before* and *after* this character):

[image: Combining character]

**Is a combining character, used alone, still a valid Unicode string?**

Or does it have to follow another character?

Comment: I think you've probably answered your own question, but it will be interesting to see if anybody can provide an authoritative response.

Comment: I had the same feeling while writing it, but it could also be a case of browsers accommodating broken Unicode to avoid rendering a blank page, just like they accommodate broken HTML :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, a combining character alone is a valid Unicode string (even though its behaviour may be weird without a base character). [Section 2.11 of the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch02.pdf) emphasises this:

> *In the Unicode Standard, all sequences of character codes are permitted.*

The presentation of such strings is described in [D52](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch03.pdf):

> - There may be no such base character, such as when a combining character is at the start of text or follows a control or format character [...] In such cases, the combining characters are called *isolated combining characters*.
> - With isolated combining characters or when a process is unable to perform graphical combination, a process may present a combining character without graphical combination; that is, it may present it as if it were a base character.

However, if you want to display a combining character by itself, it is recommended that you attach it to a no-break space base character:

> Nonspacing combining marks used by the Unicode Standard may be exhibited in apparent
>   isolation by applying them to `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE`. This convention might be
>   employed, for example, when talking about the combining mark itself as a mark, rather
>   than using it in its normal way in text (that is, applied as an accent to a base letter or in
>   other combinations).

Comment: I took a detour via Unicode 9.0 (released, but the final PDF not yet published) and via Chapter 4 Character Properties before finding the material you're quoting from Chapter 3 Conformance.  I was going to include:  
•   _These  characters  are  not  normally  used  in  isolation  unless  they  are  being
described.  They  include  such  characters  
as  accents,  diacritics,  Hebrew  points,
Arabic vowel signs, and Indic matras._ but your quotes are sufficient.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the authoritative answer. This triggers another question: if I concatenate two strings, and the second string starts with a combining character, should I explicitly add a `NO-BREAK SPACE` in between?

Comment: I actually just [asked this question separately](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38149256/759866), please feel free to answer there if you're up to it!

Answer (score 0):

Also, a dotted circle ◌ (U+25CC, `&#9676;`) character can be used as a base character.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_circle