# Proper handling of UTF8 string concatenation

Tags: unicode

I just learned that [it's OK for a Unicode string to contain isolated combining characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38126512/759866).

This triggers another question, relative to concatenation of strings starting with such characters.

I'm developing a `UTF8String` object, to make UTF-8 string handling easier.

This object has a `concat()` method, that concatenates another string to the current one.

If the second string starts with a combining character, **should I add a non-breaking space between the two strings**, to avoid combining the previously isolated first character of the second string, to the last character of the first string?

Or would it be expected to have the combination occur?

Comment: How do you *get* decomposed text in a string in the first place?  There's probably an `strLetter + strDiacritic` expression somewhere in the code, in which case it's *not* correct to add the NBSP.

Comment: It should be possible to build a Unicode string up by combining separate base characters and combining characters. I'd be very surprised by a string class that didn't allow me to do that.

Comment: Guessing at the intention of the library user is a rather bad idea.  Randomly adding spaces will be wrong 98% of the time.  Not adding them might be wrong 2% of the time but is something the library user can easily fix by himself.  Do avoid reinventing this wheel, at a minimum look at how ICU does it.

Comment: Both 'combine without adding anything' and 'combine but add NBSP' could be correct sometimes — but neither is necessarily correct all the time.  Or, in other words, it depends…it depends on the context.  Another option might be to strip leading combining characters from the second string.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, thanks for sharing them. I'm thinking particularly about user-submitted UTF-8 strings via web forms; they might contain anything, *including* strings starting with combining characters. But then it's more of a validation issue that should be tackled prior to concatenation, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm developing a UTF8String object, to make UTF-8 string handling easier. [...] should I add a non-breaking space between the two strings?

I would say definitely not. Handling byte encodings like UTF-8 is a separate, lower-level concern than handling grapheme boundaries. Mixing the two issues together would be an unexpected, unwelcome layering violation.

If you want to build a string class that treats grapheme clusters as its indivisible units that's fine, but that's a different animal (and quite a lot of work to do consistently).