# Valid Unicode String

Tags: unicode

I am trying to learn unicode handling in C++. I'll use `UTF-8` for the encoding but my question is not related at all to the encoding.

The question is simple: **Is any sequence of code points a valid unicode string?**

The reason I ask this question is the because Å can be represented as `U+00C5` or the sequence of 2 codepoints `U+0041` (A), `U+030A` (ring above). This makes me wonder if the sequence of one codepoint `U+030A` (ring above), without anything before it, is a valid unicode string. It turns out that I have been able to create a filename with that name under Linux, but I am not sure it is a valid unicode string.

Comment: This isn't really a C++ specific question, right?

Comment: Rakete1111: You are right. I have removed the C++ tag.

Comment: My advice is to not handle Unicode yourself at all, but instead use a library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a combining character be used alone in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126512/can-a-combining-character-be-used-alone-in-unicode)

Answer (score 0):

> This makes me wonder if the sequence of one codepoint `U+030A` (ring
>   above), without anything before it, is a valid unicode string

The question is invalid because `U+030A` is not a string but a code point. but yes, assuming you did encode this code point to the relevant encoding correctly, there is no problem if this code point appears alone. it does not need anything to precede it.

> It turns out that I have been able to create a filename with that name
>   under Linux

It doesn't mean squat.

Comment: David Haim: My question was about the unicode string that contains one unicode point, not about the unicode point. Thanks for your answer.