# Is there an algorithm to detect "isolated combining characters"?

Tags: regex, unicode

I am interested in detecting strings that contain "un-combined" or "dangling" combining characters. These are formally known as [isolated combining characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135244/2954547).

An example of such a string would be `"\u0303 hello"`, which starts with a `COMBINING TILDE` that is not actually combined with anything else.

Is there an algorithm for detecting such a thing?

It seems like I can search over the string looking for "combine-able" base characters, and reject any combining character that is not preceded by such a base character. But how do I know what characters are base characters? I imagine that there are also edge cases to worry about.

My objective is to reject such strings as invalid identifiers, in a programming language that supports Unicode identifiers. But this might also be useful for other text processing tasks as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you've described here is a regular language; Thus, added `regex` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode 14.0 [definitions D50, D51, D52](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/ch03.pdf#G30602) seem relevant.

You could find the *first* isolated combined character in an uninterrupted sequence of possibly multiple isolated combined characters by searching for combining characters that

- immediately follow something that is not a Letter (`L`), Number (`N`), Punctuation (`P`), Symbol (`S`) or Space Separator (`Zs`) or another combining character (`M`).

In Java-Syntax that would be:

```
(?<!\p{L}|\p{N}|\p{P}|\p{S}|\p{Zs}|\p{M})\p{M}
```

Full runnable example (Scala, here [an online interpreter](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8ofR4n6rTFOUBDjljIriwg)]:

```
val rgx = """(?<!\p{L}|\p{N}|\p{P}|\p{S}|\p{Zs}|\p{M})\p{M}""".r

val examples = List(
  "\u0303bad",
  "ok\u0303",
  "ok\u0303\u0303",
  "bad\u001F\u0303"
)

for (e <- examples) {
  println(rgx.findFirstIn(e).nonEmpty)
}
```

prints:

```
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: Thanks for uncovering this in the Unicode spec!