# How to check for Unicode well-formedness?

Tags: unicode

As many of us surely do, I accept Unicode usernames for a service, and as many of us surely have, I sometimes get people who try use the complexity of Unicode to do funnies with that. One fun thing that one can do with Unicode is begin a string with a combining character which then, upon concatenation with other strings (in log messages, user-visible messages, HTML snippets, profile pages, &c&c&c) combines with the string prior to it (usually, but not necessarily, a space). While this is rarely enough to cause serious problems, it can be strange and confusing, and while I hate being the party-pooper, I feel it is sometimes a bit too much fun for anyone to be able to have.

In my particular case, I could of course check specifically for combining characters at the start of inputs, but given the aforementioned complexity of Unicode, I don't doubt that there are a million other fun things that can be done with it, and I'm sure there are well-defined rules for Unicode to be considered well-formed, but I can't say I've been able to easily find any. It would (arguably) be nice to exorcise Zalgo in general.

So that's my question: How does one check that a Unicode string is well-formed in this context?

Comment: Do you mean _normalize_? Failing to normal user-input strings is silly in any case.

Comment: No, I don't have any particular interest in modifying the string in any way, just checking whether it "makes sense".

Comment: And yet you reject the notion of normalization? On what grounds?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but normalization would imply modifying the string, wouldn't it? I don't see what that has to do with checking for well-formedness.

Comment: Because under one definition a well formed string would normalize to itself.

Comment: Perhaps I'm having the terminology wrong here, but isn't normalization (among perhaps other things?) the process of converting between composed and decomposed forms? If so, your statement would imply that either is ill-formed, which I can't see why that it would have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zalgo is well-formed Unicode. It's strange Unicode, but it's completely legal. Beginning a string with a combining character is also completely legal. See [Can a combining character be used alone in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126512/can-a-combining-character-be-used-alone-in-unicode) for a previous discussion of this. The text cited is still present in version 14 of the spec (section 2.11):

> All combining characters can be applied to any base character and can, in principle, be used with any script. As with other characters, the allocation of a combining character to one block or another identifies only its primary usage; it is not intended to define or limit the range of characters to which it may be applied. *In the Unicode Standard, all sequences of character codes are permitted.* (Emphasis in the original.)

There is [Stream-Safe Text Format](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Stream_Safe_Text_Format) which addresses some of what you're describing, in that it limits the number of combining characters to 30, but I suspect this does not address your real concern, which is that you don't want to see things that don't feel like "real language."

Somewhat by design, that doesn't exist. Human language is so wild and varied that Unicode still hasn't captured all of it. Trying to put limits on what can be expressed is the opposite of what Unicode strives to do. So whatever you design is going to be necessarily ad hoc.

To your specific question of avoiding combining dynamic text with static text that comes before it (for example, in a log message), that is fully supported by Unicode. The code point you want is U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER. It means "even if the two code points surrounding this one would normally be joined, don't." So you can add that to your log message template to make sure the message is not corrupted in that way. No need to write special rules to modify or inspect the strings. Zero-width marks are how Unicode intends these issues to be addressed. (See also, U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK and its friends, which you may find useful to keep your log messages from having strange layouts when embedding RTL languages.)

But there is no standard way to exclude Zalgo. Zalgo is human expression, and Unicode explicitly allows it. But I'll also leave you with the next paragraph of the spec:

> This does not create an obligation on implementations to support all possible combinations equally well.

You're free to use the tools of Unicode to modify the string as you like.

Comment: I must admit I at least thought that combining characters at the start of strings would have violated some sort of well-defined well-formedness rules that we could all agree on, but if even that isn't the case, then I guess my question starts to approach some more kind of "best practices on Unicode usernames" or something that also includes thoughts on homoglyph attacks and whatnot. I will meditate on this, thank you!

Comment: It really is a hard problem. You may find [UTS #39](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr39/) informative, and more broadly [UTR #36](https://unicode.org/reports/tr36/#UTS39). There is little discussion of usernames, but at least they can give you some background.